# How to dynamically affect DNS resolver from Java runnig Application

Tags: java, http, dns, recaptcha

Is there any way how to affect local DNS resolver in Java?
I want to dynamically add entry with custom host name to be translated to local IP address (127.0.0.1) without editing file "hosts" on Windows (or different OS).

I start my program written in Java:

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5000), 1);
server.createContext(....);
server.start();
```

Everything works perfectly, when I visit "localhost:5000" in web browser.

But when I use for example "simulation.myhost.com" instead of "localhost" and start my application, I am getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateToSocketException(Net.java:131) ...
```

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea...

Comment: Why do you think? Do you have some idea how to do in in JAVA?